# Creating ssas cube in xmla structure

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube, xmla

I want to create a cube by using xmla structure, with out using the BIDS.
How to do that. What dll or references are required to get the cube.

Thanks In advance for your help

---

Mihir

Answer (score 0):

Creating a cube without BIDS isn't recommended because there are so many pitfalls defining the cube structure without guidance.

You'll need to define the cube completely in XMLA. And communicate via ADO.MD

-Update-

Starting Point XMLA cube at the msdn library [Cube Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms126710.aspx)

Starting Point Ado MD at the msdn library [AdomdCommand Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdserver.adomdcommand.aspx)

Futher reading at http://netpl.blogspot.com/2008/06/complete-olap-infrastructure-without_27.html

Comment: @d_schnell... you may correct, but i want learn that xmla struture how it behaves... if you find any source please help me

Answer (score 0):

there are 4 steps to deploy an AS cube with XMLA files:

1 : build your project solution.
2 : update the artifact files with the new string : project\bin\asDataBase, bin\configSttings, bin\deployementTargets, bin\deploymentoption
3 : execute Microsoft.Analysisservices.deployment utilitaire
4 : execute the ouput XMLA with ascmd.

regards,